# how to access struct member inside an array of structs in C

Tags: c, struct

I have an array of structs which I use to get a certain member, problem I have is that I would only like to access a particular member of a struct, not the whole struct itself. 
So e.g. if my struct is declared like this:

```
static _Plyr {
 char*  firstName; 
 int age; 
 char* lastName;
}

typedef struct _Plyr Player;
```

and I have a table of them...e..g

```
static Player Table[NUM] = {
{"John", 24,  "Wall"}, 
{"Carmelo", 33,  "Anthony"}, 
....
}
```

I'd like to have a function that returns e.g a person's last name based of their first name. So I have a *char function  and I know how to get the whole struct back but I only want to get a certain member from a particular struct in this case, their last name...so I need to fix my return statement

Part of my code

```
char* getLastName(char* string){
 char* first;
 for (int i = 0; i < REGCOUNT; i++){
    first = Table[i].firstName;
    if (strcmp(first, str) == 0){
        return &Table[i].lastName;
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried `Table[i].lastName, Table[i]->lastName,` ...and neither seems to work. I know `&Table[i]` gives me the adress of the struct itself and then I can access it from there but I'd simply like to get the members themselves and not the whole struct. Thank you for your time

Comment: `return RegTable[i].lastName` would be correct, if I understand your question. Perhaps you can elaborate on your problem, do you get build errors? Crashes when running? Unexpected output? Please read [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.

Comment: Oh and there are lots of inconsistencies in the little code you show: `_People` or `PlyrTbl`? `Table` or `RegTable`? `NUM` or `REGCOUNT`? An [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is really important!

Comment: Lastly, and totally unrelated to your problem, but symbol names with leading underscore followed by an upper-case letter (like `_People`) are reserved in all scopes for the compiler and standard library. Don't use such symbols.

Comment: and your firstname and lastname are just pointers. Who is allocating memory for them? Your code should Ideally crash if this is all you are doing in your code.

Comment: I get this warning: return makes pointer from integer without a cast. I fixed the code, that's not the issue though but I thought maybe this warning implied I'm not getting what I want.

Comment: We *still* need an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to be able to help you. And *where* do you get the warning? Lastly note that `&Table[i].lastName` gives you a pointer *to the pointer* which is often not something you want.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code,

```
typedef struct _Plyr {
    char*  firstName;
    int age;
    char* lastName;
} Player; /* typedef structure  _Plyr into  Player*/


static Player Table[] = { /* Table with NUM of items*/
        {"John", 24,  "Wall"},
        {"Carmelo", 33,  "Anthony"},
        ---------------------------
        ---------------------------
};

#define NUM (sizeof(Table)/sizeof(Player))  /* Maximum number of items in  table */


char* getLastName(char* string){
    char* first;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM; i++){
        first = Table[i].firstName;
        if (strcmp(first, string) == 0){
            return Table[i].lastName;
        }
    }
}
```

Check the comments added in code.

`&Table[i].lastName` is not a `char*`, you have to return `Table[i].lastName` to return address of `lastName`.

Answer (score 0):

you must use RegTable[i].lastName. maybe you assign the return value like this:

```
str = getLastName(str2);
```

which is wrong. you must use strcpy function like this:

```
strcpy(str,getLastName(str2));
```

don't forget to include  if you used strcpy.