# how do i acces variables inside a typedef struct

Tags: c

Okay so, i only recently started studying coding and i barely understand it.
at the start of it before the main() part of the program i have this.

```
typedef struct verado
{
    int id;
    char nev[30];
    char verCs[4];
    char email[30];
    int adas;
};
```

this stores 10 of each variable.
further on i have several functions, some of which are inside eachother and i have trouble accessing the variables from the aforementioned part.

```
void email(verado *v,int *h)
{
    char vercs[4];
    int opc;
    printf("1:A+ 2:B+ 3:AB+ 4:0+ 5:A- 6:B- 7:AB- 8:0-\n") ;
    scanf(" %d", &opc);

    switch(opc)
    {
    case 1:
        vercs[0]='A';vercs[1]='+';vercs[2]='\0';  
        printf("%s %s", vercs,(*v)[1].verCs,*h );
        break;  
    default:  
        printf("\nerror\n");
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

further on it needs to be able to compare the selected bloodtype with the bloodtypes of the stored ppl, but i can't do that if im unable to find out how to even access them.

Comment: In `email`, I assume you want to copy `vercs` into the struct pointed to by `v`. So: `v->verCs[0] = vercs[0]; v->verCs[1] = vercs[1]; ...`

Comment: You have to name it to obtain a type, for example `typedef struct verado { ... } veratype;` otherwise you need the full `struct verado`. Then if you have a function argument `veratype *v` you use this `v->id` or if it is an array `v[0].id`

Comment: "*further on i have several functions, some of which are inside eachother*" -- standard C does not support nested functions.  It is routine for a function to *call* others, but one function's body cannot appear inside another function's body.  I know of at least one C implementation that accepts that as an extension, but save yourself some trouble by sticking to standard C, at least until you have more experience.

Comment: `(*v)[1].verCs`? i think you mean `v[1].verCs`. Also, enable compiler warnings. your format strings defines 2 input strings, but you give 2 strings and a `int`.

Comment: "*this stores 10 of each variable*" -- please show us the code that (you think) says so, instead of trying to describe it.  Specifically, show the omitted tail of your `typedef` declaration, and the declarations of the variables passed to function `email()`, and the relevant call to `email()`.

Answer (score 0):

In general, to access the so called "member variables" of a struct, you'd have to use the point notation like is used e.g. [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42826350/2550406) to a different question.

In your case however, your function has access to a *pointer* as parameter. So you don't actually have an instance of `struct verado`, you have a pointer to it.
That means you should use the arrow operator. E.g. `v->id` to access the variable `id`.
The arrow does the same thing as this does: `(*v).id`. It dereferences the variable and then accesses the member variable.

As somebody explained in the comments, you also want to give your `struct verado` a type name. This way you won't have to type `struct verado` every time. So a small example showcasing what I just said could look like this:

```c
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct verado {
    int id;
} typeOfVerado;

void email(struct verado *v){
    printf("verado id: %d\n", v->id);
}

void main(){
    typeOfVerado myVerado  = { id: 3};
    email(&myVerado);
}
```

I'm not the most proficient in C, but I hope this is enough to give you some clarity for starters.